# Evaluate an improper integral using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I got stuck trying to find $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{(x+a)^2+b^2}\,dx$$ using complex analysis.

My attempt is to evaluate the contour integral of $$\int_C\frac{\log z}{(z+a)^2+b^2}\,dz$$ for some nicely chosen contour $C$. But for now the best $C$ I can think of is two segments plus two semicircles, which gives the value $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{(x+a)^2+b^2}\,dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{(x-a)^2+b^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2b}\log(a^2+b^2).$$
The problem is that the integrand is not an even function. For example, $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx$ would have been rather easy.

Please, I need some help!

Comment: Use a keyhole contour. An example to give you some ideas for how to calculate this can be found on [Example 5 of the Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_5_%E2%80%93_the_square_of_the_logarithm)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571670/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-log-x4dx1x1x2?rq=1) for a more complicated example that shows how this process can be extended to higher powers of $\log$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1480810/752) to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571670/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-log-x4dx1x1x2?rq=1) "How to evaluate $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x^2+a^2)^2} dx $" and on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2572587/752) to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2571670/752) "Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac {(\log x)^4dx}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}$". Instead of a function with $\log z$ on the numerator, we consider a function with $\log^2 z$. This is the very same method as that pointed to in the comments.

For $a,b>0$, this method gives the closed formula

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log x}{\left( x+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2b
}\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \log \left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) ,\qquad
a,b>0\tag{$\ast$}.
$$

We chose the multiple-valued function $f(z)$ with branch cut $\arg z=0$
defined as

$$
\begin{align*}
f(z) &=\frac{\log ^{2}z}{\left( z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}},\quad \text{with }
0<\arg z<2\pi ,\quad z=re^{i\theta } \\
&=\frac{\log ^{2}z}{\left( z-z_{1}\right) \left( z-z_{2}\right) }\qquad
z_{1}=-a+ib,\quad z_{2}=-a-ib,
\end{align*}
$$

and integrate it counterclockwise around the closed contour $\Gamma $
shown in the figure. This contour is indented around the branch point $O$
and consists of the circles $\gamma _{R}$ ($\left\vert z\right\vert =R$) and
$\gamma _{\varepsilon }$ ($\left\vert z\right\vert =\varepsilon $), $
0<\varepsilon <1<R$, and the segment $\left[ \varepsilon ,R\right] $
described in the positive sense above the $x$-axis and in the negative sense
below the $x$-axis.

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

$$\text{Closed contour } \Gamma $$

On the upper edge, $\theta =0$ ($r\in \left[ \varepsilon ,R\right] $) and

$$
f(z)=\frac{\left( \log r\right) ^{2}}{\left( r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}.
$$

On the lower edge, $\theta =2\pi $ ($r\in \left[ \varepsilon ,R\right] $) and

$$
f(z)=\frac{\left( \log \left( re^{i2\pi }\right) \right) ^{2}}{\left(
r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}=\frac{\left( \log r+i2\pi \right) ^{2}}{\left(
r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}.
$$

As such,

$$
\begin{align*}
I &=\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0,R\rightarrow \infty }\oint_{\Gamma}
\frac{\left( \log z\right) ^{2}}{\left( z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dz, \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \log r\right) ^{2}}{\left( r+a\right)
^{2}+b^{2}}\,dr-\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \log \left( re^{i2\pi
}\right) \right) ^{2}}{\left( re^{i2\pi }+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dr \\
&\quad+\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty }\int_{\gamma _{R}}\frac{\left( \log z\right)
^{2}}{\left( z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dz-\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow
0}\int_{\gamma _{\varepsilon }}\frac{\left( \log z\right) ^{2}}{\left(
z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dz \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \log r\right) ^{2}-\left( \log r+i2\pi
\right) ^{2}}{\left( r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dx \\
&=4\pi ^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left( r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}
\,dr-i4\pi \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log r}{\left( r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dr
\end{align*}
$$

provided that

$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty }\int_{\gamma _{R}}\frac{\left( \log z\right) ^{2}
}{\left( z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dz=\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow
0}\int_{\gamma _{\varepsilon }}\frac{\left( \log z\right) ^{2}}{\left(
z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}}\,dz=0,\quad \text{(see below).}
$$

By the residue theorem,

$$
\begin{align*}
I &=2\pi i\left( \operatorname{Res}_{z=z_{1}}f(z)+
\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_{2}}f(z)\right)  \\
&=2\pi i\left[ \operatorname{Res}_{z=z_{1}}\frac{
\left( \log z\right) ^{2}}{\left( z-z_{1}\right) \left( z-z_{2}\right) }+
\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_{2}}\frac{\left( \log z\right)
^{2}}{\left( z-z_{1}\right) \left( z-z_{2}\right) }\right]  \\
&=2\pi i\left[ \frac{\left( \log z_{1}\right) ^{2}}{z_{1}-z_{2}}+\frac{
\left( \log z_{2}\right) ^{2}}{z_{2}-z_{1}}\right]  \\
&=2\pi i\left[ \frac{\left( \log \left( -a+ib\right) \right) ^{2}}{i2b}-
\frac{\left( \log \left( -a-ib\right) \right) ^{2}}{i2b}\right]  \\
&=\frac{\pi }{b}\left[ \log \left( -a+ib\right) \right] ^{2}-\frac{\pi }{b}
\left[ \log \left( -a-ib\right) \right] ^{2}
\end{align*}
$$

We now assume that $a,b>0$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
I &=\frac{\pi }{b}\left[ \log \left( \left\vert -a+ib\right\vert \right)
+i\left( \pi -\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \right) \right] ^{2} \\
&\quad-\frac{\pi }{b}\left[ \log \left( \left\vert -a-ib\right\vert \right)
+i\left( \pi +\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \right) \right] ^{2} \\
&=\frac{\pi }{b}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\log \left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) +i\left(
\pi -\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \right) \right] ^{2} \\
&\quad-\frac{\pi }{b}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\log \left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) +i\left(
\pi +\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \right) \right] ^{2} \\
&=\frac{4\pi ^{2}}{b}\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) -i\frac{2\pi }{b}
\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \log \left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) 
\end{align*}
$$

because
$$
\log \left( \left\vert -a+ib\right\vert \right) =\log \left( \left\vert
-a-ib\right\vert \right) =\frac{1}{2}\log \left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) .
$$

Taking the imaginary part of $I$ we obtain $(\ast)$ in the form
$$
\text{Im }( I )=-4\pi \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\log r}{\left( r+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}
}\,dr=-\frac{2\pi }{b}\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right) \log \left(
a^{2}+b^{2}\right) 
$$

---

Proof that $\int_{\gamma _{R}}f,\int_{\gamma _{\varepsilon }}f\rightarrow 0$. If $z$ is any point on $\gamma _{R}$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\left\vert f(z)\right\vert  &=\frac{\left\vert \log z\right\vert ^{2}}{
\left\vert \left( z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}\right\vert },\qquad z=R\,e^{i\theta
},R>1,0<\theta <2\pi  \\
&\leq \frac{\left( \log R+2\pi \right) ^{2}}{\left\vert z+\left(
-z_{1}\right) \right\vert \left\vert z+\left( -z_{2}\right) \right\vert }, \\
&\leq \frac{\left( \log R+2\pi \right) ^{2}}{\left\vert R-\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}
\right\vert ^{2}}\leq M_{R}
\end{align*}
$$

where

$$
M_{R}=\frac{4\pi \log R+4\pi
^{2}+\log ^{2}R}{R^{2}+\left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) -2R\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}
$$

because
$$
\left\vert z+\left( -z_{1}\right) \right\vert \geq \left\vert R-\left\vert
z_{1}\right\vert \right\vert ,\left\vert z+\left( -z_{2}\right) \right\vert
\geq \left\vert R-\left\vert z_{2}\right\vert \right\vert ,\left\vert
z_{1}\right\vert =\left\vert z_{2}\right\vert =\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}.
$$

This means that

$$
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \int_{\gamma _{R}}f(z)\,dz\right\vert  &\leq M_{R}\times \,2\pi R
\\
&=\frac{4\pi \log R+4\pi ^{2}+\log ^{2}R}{R^{2}+\left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right)
-2R\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\times \,2\pi R\longrightarrow 0\qquad \left(
R\rightarrow \infty \right) .
\end{align*}
$$

Similarly, if $z$ is any point on $\gamma _{\varepsilon }$
$$
\begin{align*}
\left\vert f(z)\right\vert  &=\frac{\left\vert \log z\right\vert ^{2}}{
\left\vert \left( z+a\right) ^{2}+b^{2}\right\vert },\qquad z=\varepsilon
\,e^{i\theta },0<\varepsilon <1,0<\theta <2\pi  \\
&\leq \frac{\left( \log \varepsilon +2\pi \right) ^{2}}{\left\vert z+\left(
-z_{1}\right) \right\vert \left\vert z+\left( -z_{2}\right) \right\vert } \\
&\leq \frac{\left( \log \varepsilon +2\pi \right) ^{2}}{\left\vert
\varepsilon -\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\right\vert ^{2}}\leq M_{\varepsilon },
\end{align*}
$$

where

$$
M_{\varepsilon }=\frac{4\pi \log \varepsilon +4\pi ^{2}+\log
^{2}\varepsilon }{\varepsilon ^{2}+\left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) -2\varepsilon 
\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \int_{\gamma _{\varepsilon }}f(z)\,dz\right\vert  &\leq
M_{\varepsilon }\times \,2\pi \varepsilon \qquad z=\rho \,e^{i\theta },\rho
<1 \\
&\leq \frac{4\pi \log \varepsilon +4\pi ^{2}+\log ^{2}\varepsilon }{
\varepsilon ^{2}+\left( a^{2}+b^{2}\right) -2\varepsilon \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}
\times \,2\pi \varepsilon \longrightarrow 0\qquad \left( \varepsilon
\rightarrow 0\right) .
\end{align*}
$$